# Symbol levels for graduated colours not working in ArcMap 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

In ArcMap I have set a draw order on my data, however ArcMap is not displaying it as instructed. The red values should be drawn ontop of the green/yellow.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting your project and Arcmap? Does the problem persist?

Comment: Are you positive that the layer properties box you have open is for the layer that you are displaying in the map? The layer in the map looks to be polygons, but the properties box is displaying lines...

Comment: Yes, it is lines, it's just a very large (A1) map.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working in the end, I went to advanced view and re-entered the order manually, I'm not sure why the original view didn't work as the layers were in the correct order.